# XCTestExpectation doesn't wait for given amount of time

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift

I've written a test that checks if some value will go down to zero until 5 seconds. Every each second NSTimer fires a method that decrements this value by one.

It looks like this:

```
    let foo = SomeObject(initWithTime: 5)
    let expectation = expectationWithDescription("Ohai")
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: foo, selector: Selector("decrement"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    XCTAssertTrue(foo.isFinished, "Foo is finished, so it should be true")
    expectation.fulfill()
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5.0, handler: nil)
```

isFinished sets to true when foo reaches zero. Timer works fine, but expectation doesn't wait for 5 seconds, just crashes instantly. What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your XCTAssertTrue fail immediately since foo is probably not finished when it is called immediately.